# How to create an HTML link?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have created a JSON file with various data:

```
[
  {
    "date": "17.06.",
    "event": "The Stoles gig",
    "url": "http://thestoles.com/"
  },
  {
    "date": "25.06.",
    "event": "The Editors release an EP",
    "url": "http://theeditors.com/"
  }
]
```

Everything is rendered correctly in the HTML file, except for the URL,  which doesn't show as a link.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.getJSON('feeds.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            $('#feeds').append(item['date'] + item['event'] + item['url'] + "</br>");
        });
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want a link, you have to create an anchor element (`<a>`). http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html (FYI, this has nothing to do with JSON, so I updated your question).

Comment: Jquery is very useful creating elements and adding them to the dom

Comment: I have your answer below.... :)

Comment: a link is an element, you need to set your url in `'href'` property of an `'<a href='..'> text shown </a>'` in that .append

Comment: Why the downvote a valid question, just one with an easy answer to non beginnners!!! This site annoys me sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Just do this...

You need to put the link in an `<a>` tag...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.getJSON('feeds.json', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        $('#feeds').append(item.date + item.event + "<a href='"+item.url+"'>"+item.url+"</a></br>");
    });
   });
 });
```

Or if you dont want to actually display the link, and just have the Event name hyperlinked...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $.getJSON('feeds.json', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        $('#feeds').append(item.date + "<a href='"+item.url+"'>"+item.event+"</a></br>");
    });
   });
 });
```

Comment: This is better answer than @Mr. Bombastic

Comment: hey guys, none of the above is working. If I hyperlink it inside the code the link just doesn't show at all

Answer (score 1):

You've to sourround the URL by an anchor-tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.getJSON('feeds.json', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            $('#feeds').append(item['date'] + item['event'] + '<a href="'+item['url']+'">Link</a></br>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem, I always hate when people point out my syntax error and fix it for me....I enjoy finding it myself, so I assume others might wanna as well....:P